# Python Ctypes with RaspberryPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ctypes, ffi

I'm working to write a ctypes wrapper in PySodium for a libsodium routine `crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt`, the routine is defined as:

```
def crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt(message,
                                         ad,
                                         nonce,
                                         key):

    mlen  = ctypes.c_ulonglong(len(message))
    adlen = ctypes.c_ulonglong(len(ad))

    c    =  ctypes.create_string_buffer(mlen.value+16L)
    clen  = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)

    sodium.crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt(c,
                                                clen,
                                                message,
                                                mlen,
                                                ad,
                                                adlen,
                                                None,
                                                nonce,
                                                key)
    return c.raw
```

My test driver is:

```
from pysodium import  crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt
from bitstring import BitStream

key = BitStream(hex="4290bcb154173531f314af57f3be3b5006da371ece272afa1b5dbdd1100a1007")
nonce = BitStream(hex="cd7cf67be39c794a")
ad = BitStream(hex="87e229d4500845a079c0")
msg = BitStream(hex="86d09974840bded2a5ca")

print(key)
print(nonce)
print(ad)
print(msg)

m = crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt(message=msg.bytes,
                                         ad=ad.bytes,
                                         nonce=nonce.bytes,
                                         key=key.bytes)

edata = BitStream(bytes=m)
print(edata)
```

and much to my surprise (being the first time I used libsodium or PySodium or ctypes) it worked without a hitch on an AMD x86_64 system.  Unfortunately when I ported everything over to the RaspberryPi (ARMv6) things came undone.  I ran `gdb python-gdb` against it and can see the stacktrace:

```
#0  chacha_keysetup (x=0xbeffefc4, k=0x0) at crypto_stream/chacha20/ref/stream_chacha20_ref.c:69
#1  0x4059dcbc in crypto_stream_chacha20_ref (c=0xbefff0e4 "\264\335\024", clen=, n=0x0, k=0x0)
    at crypto_stream/chacha20/ref/stream_chacha20_ref.c:241
#2  0x40556f60 in crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt (c=0x405385f4 "\206Йt\204\v\336", , clen=0x437f44, 
    m=0x0, mlen=4634464344201201140, ad=0xa , adlen=1079196860, nsec=0xa , npub=
    0x0, k=0x0) at crypto_aead/chacha20poly1305/sodium/aead_chacha20poly1305.c:49
#3  0x40501368 in ffi_call_VFP () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes_d.so
#4  0x40500930 in ffi_call () from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes_d.so
#5  0x404ecf10 in _call_function_pointer (flags=4353, pProc=0x40556ea8 , avalues=0xbefff2d8, 
    atypes=0xbefff2a8, restype=0x402a6ed8, resmem=0xbefff308, argcount=9)
    at /build/python2.7-xJctIx/python2.7-2.7.3/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c:827
#6  0x404edb84 in _ctypes_callproc (pProc=0x40556ea8 , argtuple=
    (, , '\x86\xd0\x99t\x84\x0b\xde\xd2\xa5\xca', , '\x87\xe2)\xd4P\x08E\xa0y\xc0', , None, '\xcd|\xf6{\xe3\x9cyJ', "B\x90\xbc\xb1T\x1751\xf3\x14\xafW\xf3\xbe;P\x06\xda7\x1e\xce'*\xfa\x1b]\xbd\xd1\x10\n\x10\x07"), flags=4353, argtypes=0x0, restype=
    , checker=0x0)
    at /build/python2.7-xJctIx/python2.7-2.7.3/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c:1174
#7  0x404e5154 in PyCFuncPtr_call (self=0x40518e90, inargs=
    (, , '\x86\xd0\x99t\x84\x0b\xde\xd2\xa5\xca', , '\x87\xe2)\xd4P\x08E\xa0y\xc0', , None, '\xcd|\xf6{\xe3\x9cyJ', "B\x90\xbc\xb1T\x1751\xf3\x14\xafW\xf3\xbe;P\x06\xda7\x1e\xce'*\xfa\x1b]\xbd\xd1\x10\n\x10\x07"), kwds=0x0)
    at /build/python2.7-xJctIx/python2.7-2.7.3/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c:3913
#8  0x0002fa08 in PyObject_Call (func=, arg=
    (, , '\x86\xd0\x99t\x84\x0b\xde\xd2\xa5\xca', , '\x87\xe2)\xd4P\x08E\xa0y\xc0', , None, '\xcd|\xf6{\xe3\x9cyJ', "B\x90\xbc\xb1T\x1751\xf3\x14\xafW\xf3\xbe;P\x06\xda7\x1e\xce'*\xfa\x1b]\xbd\xd1\x10\n\x10\x07"), kw=0x0) at ../Objects/abstract.c:2529
```

Reading up on what FFI actually does I've got to think that for some reason when ctypes passes the data off to FFI it gets corrupted along the way.  I've searched trying to find whether there's some known issue with ctypes/FFI etc. on the Pi/ARM platform but have drawn a blank.  If it's my actual binding code I'd be interested to know why it behaves correctly on the x86_64 vs. ARM.

And finally, I'm open to suggestions to use an alternative to ctypes (though not crazy about SWIG, if that's what it takes).

Comment: You should probably try setting explicit `argtypes` (and `restype`, but that's less important, especially for functions that return `int`). It's hard enough to debug these problems when you're not sure whether you created the values wrong vs. were wrong about the signature…

Comment: For reference, here's [the docs for the function](http://doc.libsodium.org/secret-key_cryptography/aead.html). It looks like you got the types right at first glance…

Comment: One last thing: according to [Bindings for other languages](http://doc.libsodium.org/bindings_for_other_languages/README.html), there are two different sets of Python bindings for libsodium. Have you tried them both? Are they missing functions you need, or do they not run on RPi, or…?

Comment: Thanks for tip with `argtypes`, I'll take a look there.  I took a glance at the other Python binding and they are on an older version of `libsodium` altogether, but I've put in an issue request hopefully I can work with them to get it updated.

Comment: If they both use `ctypes`, maybe the source to the other one has some ideas that can help, even if you can't use it directly?

Comment: It looks like PyNaCl uses a direct bind to FFI if that makes sense.  Luckily the project isn't halted I can continue to prototype on an x86, but I'll keep coming back to the Pi and try to update this thread as soon as possible.

Comment: By "FFI" you mean the [`cffi`](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/) library? If so, `cffi` has less of a learning curve than `ctypes`, so don't let that throw you off. Also, while `ctypes` makes it easy to get things hooked up, but the hard part is translating all the declarations; `cffi` is the other way around (at least if you use the API rather than ABI bindings), so PyNaCl may have already done all the hard work, making it easier for you to extend it than PySodium.

Comment: @abarnert The issue was failing to use `ctypes.byref()` - throw that in and all is well on the ARM processor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clen` below needs to be passed by reference using the `ctypes.byref()` method.  From the Ctypes [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html):  *Sometimes a C api function expects a pointer to a data type as parameter, probably to write into the corresponding location, or if the data is too large to be passed by value. This is also known as passing parameters by reference.  ctypes exports the byref() function which is used to pass parameters by reference.*  For whatever reason *not* using `ctypes.byref()` poses no problem on an x86 platform, but did on the ARM processor.  Updating the code to use it cleared the segmentation fault on the ARM and also works as expected on x86.

```
def crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt(message,
                                         ad,
                                         nonce,
                                         key):

    mlen  = ctypes.c_ulonglong(len(message))
    adlen = ctypes.c_ulonglong(len(ad))

    c    =  ctypes.create_string_buffer(mlen.value+16L)
    clen  = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)

    sodium.crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt(c,
                                                ctypes.byref(clen),
                                                message,
                                                mlen,
                                                ad,
                                                adlen,
                                                None,
                                                nonce,
                                                key)
    return c.raw
```

The bindings for `crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_encrypt`, `crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_decrypt`, and `crypto_stream_chacha20_xor` are available on a fork of pysodium at https://github.com/iachievedit/pysodium until a pull request is submitted and accepted.

Comment: Looking at the function you're wrapping, this makes perfect sense. The `clen` is an output parameter—you pass a pointer to a `long long` and it fills in the length. By passing it `0`, you're passing it a NULL pointer. Apparently it's OK with that. But you're also passing it a 64-bit NULL pointer, which will work on almost any 64-bit platform, or any platform that passes args in registers—but on the stack, it means you've screwed up every subsequent argument.

Comment: By the way, this is *exactly* why you want to use `argtypes`. If you'd declared the function as taking a `POINTER(c_ulonglong)` argument, you would have gotten an easy-to-diagnose `TypeError` from `ctypes` instead of a platform-dependent segfault…

Comment: Ah, terrific, after reading the example `printf.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p, c_int, c_double]` that makes sense.  Sort of a static declaration to catch errors.

Comment: Exactly. The parameter types can be used to catch errors, and even to do some automatic conversions. Even C can, e.g., convert an `int` to a `long` if you give it a prototype for the function, but `ctypes` can do all kinds of nice conversions for you, and you can extend it any way you want.